# How to run Dunnett C post hoc test in R?

Tags: r, statistics, posthoc

I ran a two-way anova in r with my data set (unequal sample sizes, unequal variance): 1 variable measured across 3 species (with males and females in each species).
This produces a significant result between species, so I want to know which pairwise comparisons produce the significance. I know that there are functions in packages for performing post hoc tests in R:
e.g.

Dunnett's post hoc test from http://www.uwlax.edu/faculty/toribio/math305_fall09/multiple.txt.
Packages required: "multcomp", "mvtnorm", "survival", "splines"

```
library(multcomp)           
test.dunnett=glht(anova_results,linfct=mcp(method="Dunnett"))
confint(test.dunnett)
plot(test.dunnett)
```

*note: glht is described in "multcomp"

But Dunett's test is designed to compare all groups to a control. Instead I want to compare all groups to each other, the Dunnett C. 
Does anyone know of a package that performs Dunnett C or knows how to code it? (equation at: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v21r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Falg_posthoc_unequalvar.htm)

Comment: You seem to be using syntax that is not described in the help pages for `glht`. Is that code not throwing errors for you?

Comment: Thanks DWin, I edited the post with more detailed code. I don't get errors. But I don't want Dunnett, I want to run Dunnett C. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

(So the `method` item was defined elsewhere and was not expected to be the name of an argument as I had assumed.) There were three examples of multiple comparisons in the code linked at the uwlax.edu website. The second one gave what it appears you want, namely an all-pairs set of comparisons. It isn't "Dunnett's C" but my experience is that the authors of R generally give the most powerful tests and make it less convenient to use out-moded tests. The citations in the SPSS website for the Dunnett's C code are 40 years old. The citations for the `ghlt` and TukeyHSD functions are much more recent and the authors are highly respected. I see no compelling reason to use Dunnett's C and would instead use the TukeyHSD option that achieves your goals:

```
 method1=c(96,79,91,85,83,91,82,87)
 method2=c(77,76,74,73,78,71,80)
 method3=c(66,73,69,66,77,73,71,70,74)

 score=c(method1,method2,method3)
 method=c(rep(1,length(method1)),
          rep(2,length(method2)),
          rep(3,length(method3)))
 method=factor(method)
 anova_results=aov(score~method)        
 anova_results
#------------
Call:
   aov(formula = score ~ method)

Terms:
                   method Residuals
Sum of Squares  1090.6190  387.2143
Deg. of Freedom         2        21

Residual standard error: 4.29404
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
#----------
summary(anova_results)
#------------------
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
method       2 1090.6   545.3   29.57 7.81e-07 ***
Residuals   21  387.2    18.4                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 TukeyHSD(anova_results)
#--------------
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = score ~ method)

$method
          diff       lwr         upr     p adj
2-1 -11.178571 -16.78023  -5.5769151 0.0001590
3-1 -15.750000 -21.00924 -10.4907592 0.0000006
3-2  -4.571429 -10.02592   0.8830666 0.1113951

 TukeyHSD(anova_results, ordered=T)
#---------------    
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = score ~ method)

$method
         diff        lwr      upr     p adj
2-3  4.571429 -0.8830666 10.02592 0.1113951
1-3 15.750000 10.4907592 21.00924 0.0000006
1-2 11.178571  5.5769151 16.78023 0.0001590
```

Comment: Tukey's HSD assumes that you have equal variance, normality, and independence. It also assumes equal sample sizes (though you can get around that).

My data does not have homogeneity of variance (from Levene's test), nor are all variables normally distributed. Dunnett's C was designed specifically for those situations. Which is why I want to figure out how to use Dunnett's C in R.

Comment: You could then be look at robust methods.

Comment: I'm looking for Dunnettes C too. Also, do not buy a boat. Talk your friend into buying a boat instead. It's much better that way, trust me..